# RichText label or 'flow' layout for text in iOS (Xamarin/MonoTouch)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to repduce a similar sort of layout as in the screenshot below from the Digg app..

Notice that each list entry has a title in bold followed by the source, posted time and finally if there is enough space the start of the description line.

The question is what is the best way to achieve this in iOS? With some posts having longer titles than others I cannot simply say that the title label is 40px high and then place the Source label at 45 as the title will sometimes be longer and sometimes shorter.

Do I have to calculate the height of the label based on its contents before arranging the layout or is there some better way of doing this in iOS so that the views 'below' are automatically moved down?

Another alternative would be some sort of rich text label that I could add all the text to and have it automatically wrap round moving the later text down but I cannot find any sort of control in standard iOS / Xamarin (MonoTouch).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated?

[image: Flow Layout]

Comment: Basically, you can create the custom tableview.

Comment: I'm repeating myself: but MonoTouch.Dialog will be a life saver for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard the simplest way to achieve this result is to define different prototype cells. For example, you could define four different prototype cells, each one with a different layout like those shown in the example picture you provided. You can dequeue the appropriate cell based on the content you want to display so there is no need to adjust the layout in the code.

If you are doing everything in code, it's a lot more complicated since you have to build your own "layout engine" to adjust size and position of the views in your cell. You can have a look at [XibFree](http://www.toptensoftware.com/xibfree/) or use MonoTouch.Dialog as suggested in the comments.